# Will swapping the input terminals on my op amp give me a negative reference voltage?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I am using an AD8031 op amp which outputs a 1.6V reference voltage with the circuit in the picture. I am powering it using 3.3V. I thought the output would be negative since the feedback is negative.

How can I get a negative voltage output? Will swapping the input terminals accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

1. Negative feedback adjusts the output so that the inverting input voltage matches the non-inverting input voltage. Since the non-inverting input is at half-supply the output voltage will be too.

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

From the internal schematic of the 741 op-amp it should be clear that the output can source current from the \$ V_{S+} \$ rail via Q14 or sink current to the \$ V_{S-} \$ rail via Q20.

2. In general, op-amps output stages are configured similarly to the bad-old 741. If the upper output transistor turns on the output is pulled towards positive rail. If the lower transistor is turned on the output is pulled towards the negative rail which is 0 V in your schematic. It is not possible to generate an output voltage higher than the positive supply pin or more negative than the negative supply pin.

> How can I get a negative voltage output?

You can't with that circuit. You need a negative voltage power supply or DC-DC converter.

> Will swapping the input terminals accomplish this?

No. This should be clear by now.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not as simple as swapping the input terminals.

1. You must still provide negative feedback for the circuit to be stable. By swapping the input terminals you'd have positive feedback instead of negative.
2. You need to provide a negative power supply if you want to get a negative output.

You can google "op-amp inverting amplifier" to find examples of the circuit you want.

The standard inverting amplifier does not have "near infinite" input impedance like the non-inverting amplifier does, so you'll also want to account for the amplifier circuit's input impedance loading the voltage divider if you need a very particular output voltage.

Comment: In the case of an inverting configuration, there is no need of voltage divider since the input resistor R1 = 2R2 could be directly connected to the positive rail. Thus the "inverting amplifier" would actually be an "inverting attenuator". Noises can be reduced by connecting a capacitor in parallel to R2 (like an inverting integrator).